# How to find/select correct bolt for shock absorber on old boat trailer

Tags: shock-absorber

While not a car or truck question, I hope a boat trailer question is ok.

I have a trailer for my boat. The trailer (and the boat) is from 1960. After 40 years in the family, the shock absorbers have now failed so I am replacing them. The bolts for the existing shocks are corroded beyond use and not the correct diameter for the new shocks.

I’ve got replacement shocks from Gabriel (model 81108) if that info is needed.

So my question is how do I source appropriate replacement bolts? Everywhere I search, the search criteria is based on model/year of the bike/car/truck/etc. Given the trailer is from 1960, there is no way to search in this way.

The new bolts should be 12mm in diameter and at lease 79mm in length. The thread pattern isn’t important as it is just a nut/bolt application (very simple installation, nut/bolt the shock to both the frame and the axle). The trailer carries a 13’ fibreglass boat with a 30hp outboard, so not a heavy application.

I’m in Canada. Any suggestions on how to try and source replacement bolts in this situation?
Thanks

Comment: Go to a garage - they will have a nut&bolt box, 1/2 hr rummaging will find suitable bolts and not cheap mild steel - need hardened ines.

Comment: If you use a narrower bolt it's going to rattle around in the mount, if you get a wider bolt you'll need to drill the mount out a bit, something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Take the old bolt (or the dimensions) to a fastener dealer, such as Bolt Supply House,  or Fastenal. They should be able to get you a replacement.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found a company Bolts Plus which I was able to search by size and grade.